# How can I persist a parent with two references to same transient child?

Tags: hibernate, persistence, parent-child, hibernate-mapping

I have a hibernate parent-child relationship where the parent has a separate, one-to-one relationship with one of the children. If the referenced child is transient, how can I persist the parent and child?

I have a schema like this:

```
PARENT(PARENT_ID, SOME_DATA, SPECIAL_CHILD_ID)
CHILD(CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID, CHILD_DATA)
```

...and entities like this:

```
class Parent {
    Child getSpecialChild();
    SortedSet<Child> getChildren();
}

class Child {
    Parent getParent();
}
```

I am creating a transient parent, and transient child, in the same transaction. When I try to persist the parent (cascading both specialChild and children), I get a unique constraint error from the DB, since hibernate tries to generate two inserts (one for the specialChild, and another for the same child in children). I have verified using the debugger that specialChild and children() hold the same *instance* of the transient child object.

In my real business case, I was able to work around the problem by removing the SPECIAL_CHILD_ID field. If I really needed to do it this way, though, how would I go about correctly persisting my data?